# Trigger AWS Lambda in Java for the newly uploaded file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a requirement where I want to trigger the AWS Lambda function written in Java when a file is uploaded on S3 bucket. The condition is that the function should pick-up the latest file in the bucket. Right now, I have the lambda function which picks up the specified file (having already specified file name). But as per the requirement, the file name can be anything(eg. web-log-). Is there any way to do that?

Since with lambda functions, we have access to the event object, can I use it to find out the recently uploaded file?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html ? Was anything specific unclear?

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk Yeah! I checked that. But I could not find any information to work on the recently uploaded file. The situation is like this- Suppose there is a S3 bucket and there are already 4-5 files uploaded. As soon as the 6th file is uploaded, I want to trigger the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [the AWS Lambda S3 tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html), which should show how the uploaded object is passed in as event data. The example code contains a line which should point you in the right direction:

```
event.Records[0].s3.object.key
```

Comment: That is the perfect solution. `String key = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();` The key variable holds the name of the file which trigerred the event. Thanks for your suggestion!